# trying to identify a book about humans living inside giant plants.

Tags: story-identification

The humans were threatened by the rise and fall of sap levels and rarely left the plants but climbed up and down inside where they lived at different levels inside. I read this about 25 years ago but grateful for any ideas.

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like the final chapters of  [The Genocides](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Genocides) by [Thomas M. Disch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_M._Disch) (aliens seed plants on earth that kill all other life - a few remaining humans flee to live inside the plants). A superbly written book (and a contender for the 1965 Hugo Award) but incredibly depressing (pretty much a scifi version of Lord of the Flies on steroids).

Comment: Thanks, I've looked up this book and it sounds like the right one!

Answer (score -1):

Could also be the  The Integral Trees By Larry Niven
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Integral_Trees